# sass: p html element re-writes nested p html element, and need to have different styles

Tags: html, sass

currently on my sass project the p {} and blockquote p {} have the same values. example.

```
.component {
    p {
       border:1px solid red;
    }

    blockquote {
        p {
           border:1px solid blue;
          }
    }
}
```

is always red. there is a way to make blockquote p to be appart using sass?

```
<div>
<p>hello world</p>
<blockquote>
  <p>world is yours</p>
</blockquote>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the html? Do you have a p nested in your blockquote nested in your component?

Comment: I'm confused here, as this is working as intended for me. A paragraph inside a blockquote, which is in turn inside a .component div, gets a blue border. If there's a paragraph inside the .component but is outside the blockquote, then it's red.

Comment: I've updated my question so you can see the HTML. I ended up adding !important on the first <p>

Comment: I still don't understand, this definitely looks like it's working as intended (https://codepen.io/emsixteen/pen/abKGvbp). Can you explain your issue a bit further?